# Workflow is not working for library on SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow, infopath, forms-services

I am using SharePoint 2013, I published my InfoPath form on SharePoint library. And created the workflow. I published the workflow many times to get the form results after form submissions. But the workflow is not showing for that particular library. I am not able see whether the workflow is running:

[image: re]

From the library setting, I am able to see the workflow's name which I have created on SharePoint designer but not showing by click Add a workflow under the List. What issues can be there?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the workflow as a reusable workflow?

From the second image you provided, the workflow(Safety Audit Checklist) is a reusable workflow, you need to create a workflow in UI based on the reusable workflow as the second image and type a name in the **Name** line and set related start options(for example, start it manually). Then you should could start the workflow manually. Please have a try.

To use the workflow created by SharePoint Designer directly, you need to create a list workflow instead of reusable workflow:
[image]

Comment: I need to use the workflow, I have created from the SharePoint designer, I have to use this after publish the workflow. Second image showing the workflow name which I have provided in the SharePoint designer workflow. I am trying enter the Name and publish but it causing the issue. How I can use the workflow directly after publish from SharePoint what issue can be there?

Comment: If you need to use the workflow which is created by SharePoint Designer directly, you need to create a list workflow for your list instead of reusable workflow. I have uploaded a screenshot about list workflow, you can check.

Comment: I have created the list workflow for the library. But seems not working while I am submitting the InfoPath from SharePoint. What issues can be there?

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue before.

You should look for errors in your SharePoint database.

Try to look for errors these table:

```
[WFInstanceManagementDB].[dbo].[DebugTraces]

[WFInstanceManagementDB].[dbo].[Instances]
```

Even an unused variable can sometime break the SharePoint Designer's Workflow.